# Have any of the designers of D&D explained why Strength increases Hit Chance?

Tags: dungeons-and-dragons, history-of-gaming, ability-scores, attack-roll, designer-reasons

This is a personal bias, but when I think high strength score, the imagery I get is:

[image: Bill Kazmaier]

When it comes to accuracy of a muscle-bound and bulky person, the imagery I get is:

[image: Ali Bobbing and Weaving]

Bruce Lee had stated he didn't want to have overly bulky muscles because it would affect his agility and accuracy. He did [believe in weight training](http://www.allbrucelee.com/article/why_bruce_lee_turned_to_weight_t.htm) to make his muscles more dense, but that mostly was for grip and striking force.<sup>1</sup>

I started playing with AD&D 2<sup>nd</sup> Edition, and even back then an 18 strength gave you +1 Hit and +2 to damage.

**Have any D&D developers given any reasoning for why the Strength score, specifically, gives a bonus to hit?**

As I recall, being big and strong doesn't actually help you hit a baseball, but may help you in making that ball you hit a home run.

<sub><sup>1</sup> Bruce Lee explains this throughout the *Tao of Jeet Kune Do*.</sub>

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because [designer intent questions are off-topic](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/q/7964/14878).

Answer (score 29, accepted):

**The original reason was to differentiate the Fighting Man from the other classes as a combat specialist**

The original Strength bonus to hit, solely available to Fighting Men (what we now call Fighters/Martials) was not introduced until the Greyhawk Supplement to OD&D (1 Feb 1975, TSR).

In the first combat system, the only original bonus "+ to hit" was for Dexterity for missile fire. (Unless you had a magic weapon, for example.)

> Page 11, Men and Magic, TSR 1974:  +1 to hit with missiles with Dexterity
> above 12 (my note: 13 Dex or greater yielded +1 to hit with missiles).

Strength above 13 gave a Fighting Man an experience point bonuses of 5%; Strength above 15 gave a 10% XP bonus, but neither gave a bonus to hit nor to damage.  A Strength based bonus to hit was at best indirect -- with more Strength you'd get to a higher level sooner.  A second level fighter hit AC 2 on a 17, and 4th level fighter (Hero) was the next table up and hit AC 2 on a 15, a 7th level hit AC 2 with a 12, etc. (Page 19, Men and Magic, "to hit" per the table.)

- Note: the Holmes "blue book" kept this approach. (Page 6, D&D; TSR, 1977)<sup>1</sup>.

This changed in the first OD&D supplement: Greyhawk (the most common addendum / correction / update to OD&D).

Greyhawk page 4 (devs = **Gary Gygax / Rob Kuntz**):

> Other character types may engage in hand-to-hand combat, *but only
> true fighting men* are able to use their Strength and Dexterity to
> utmost advantage."

With that point in mind, we proceed to page 7 of Greyhawk:

> "Strength also aids the fighting man in his ability to both score a
> hit upon an adversary, and damage it."
>
> "Fighters of exceptional strength are now far more formidable
> opponents ..."

Then on page 8 of Greyhawk, we note that only Fighting Men

> " ... with a dexterity of greater than 14 can use their unusual manual
> dexterity to attempt to dodge or parry opponents attacks."

Summed up: only the martial characters could, via their profession, take advantage of their Strength to land an effective / telling blow and use their Dexterity to avoid getting hit.  Anyone else could be strong, but would not get the advantage of "+ to hit."  Anyone else could be agile, but since they weren't professional fighters, the Dex based armor class advantage didn't accrue to them.

**Simple Answer to "Why?"**

**To make Fighters more formidable opponents.** (Fighters tended to be melee specialists / tanks from the beginning.)

Commentary: it was understood during the play tests that went on where D&D first grew that the problem of the Linear Fighter and Quadratic Mage (as we call it now) was looming.

**But that approach didn't last very long.**

This restriction to Fighting Men of the Strength benefit to hit, and to damage,  was lifted in the 1e AD&D PHB.  The "Why" on that is another matter, given the speed at which the game was growing.

- BECMI applied a less complex version of that same bonus for high scores in abilities, per page B7 of Basic D&D, Moldvay (Mentzer), TSR, 1980.  Str bonus for hit and damage was +1, +2, +3 for 13-15, 16-17, 18 respectively. Similar bonuses were applied to other attributes. That score-to-bonus relationship can still be found in 5e, for all attributes, albeit with a few refinements.

While only Fighting Men and their sub-classes could benefit from Extraordinary Strength (18 Str Fighters rolled percentile dice 01-00 for additional benefits) in AD&D 1e, the stronger-than-average Cleric would do a bit more damage when he whacked someone with a mace.  The AD&D 1e system formed the backbone of what we play to this day, for all of the variations that have come to pass. (As did BECMI, which took a similar approach.)

The "+ to hit" and "+ damage" based on stat ability is rooted in making the martial character stand out in combat.  This makes a lot of sense, when you begin to apply real world comparisons between people who really know how to fight (professionals) versus anyone else.

---

<sup>1</sup> Of passing interest, but off topic for this answer, the cover of the book says "The Original Adult Fantasy Role Playing Game for 3 or more players."

Comment: Not a designer note, but I'd also point out that if AC accounts for both chance to hit,and chance to land a telling blow (ie one that gets past armor), then strength makes a lot more sense as the modifier.  Had they not munged together those two components (as other systems have chosen not to), it'd make less sense.